# Alamofire build fails: issues in Manager.swift , Request.swift and ResponseSerialization.swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

I've added Alamofire framework in my project and after that if I try to build the project it raises errors in these Alamofire files: `Manager.swift , Request.swift and ResponseSerialization.swift`

Here are the screenshots of the errors:

[image: All Errors]
 [image: Errors in Manager.swift] [image: Errors in ResponseSerialization.swift] [image: Errors in ResponseSerialization.swift]  [image: Errors in Request.swift]

Comment: did you add `import Alamofire`?

Comment: No, build just after adding `Alamofire` shows the error. `import Alamofire` gives the error too, I had tested that in another project

Comment: At my project, I need `import Alamofire` in all files that use Alamofire, otherwise it won't compile. Also, at [Alamofire/Usage](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#usage) they use it too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Xcode.

The Alamofire version you've installed targets the last Swift version, but your Xcode version is older than that, so it doesn't recognize the syntax.

Comment: I've just updated it. Now the version is Version `7.2.1 (7C1002)` 
still getting the same errors

Comment: Current Xcode version is 7.3.1 (7D1014) https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/ The 7.2.1 version you just installed is still too old for this version of Alamofire.